# GTK button from stock does not show up?

Tags: c, gtk, codeblocks

I am using GTK in CodeBlocks (Windows 7) and I tried to create a `gtk_button_new_from_stock` so I used this code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    GtkWidget* Window=NULL ,  *Btn = NULL;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    Window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(Window), 320 ,200);


    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(Window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit),    NULL);


    Btn = gtk_button_new_from_stock(GTK_STOCK_QUIT);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(Btn), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(Window), Btn);

    gtk_widget_show_all(Window);

    gtk_main();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The problem is: this button does not show the image. Is there any other way to create a button with an image on it?

Answer (score 0):

Set the size of the image with `GTK_ICON_SIZE_BUTTON`:

```
GtkWidget *button;
GtkWidget *image;

button = gtk_button_new();
image = gtk_image_new_from_stock(GTK_STOCK_QUIT, GTK_ICON_SIZE_BUTTON);
gtk_button_set_image(GTK_BUTTON(button), image);
```